# Smooth scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar

**My issues:**

1. When scrolling upwards it scrubs at the end
2. When scrolling downwards, it will stuck at the end

Can anyone help me with this? I'm not good at the javascript, and I have no chance of finding out where the problem is. Scrolling is nice, but these two problems are pretty unpleasant. Try scrolling up and down completely to show my issues.

```js
function Scrollbar(){
 new SmoothScroll(document,65,15) // target | speed | smooth
}

function SmoothScroll(target, speed, smooth) {
 if (target == document)
  target = (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body) // cross browser support for document scrolling
 var moving = false
 var pos = target.scrollTop
 target.addEventListener('mousewheel', scrolled, false)
 target.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', scrolled, false)

 function scrolled(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // disable default scrolling
  var delta = e.delta || e.wheelDelta;
  if (delta === undefined) {
   //we are on firefox
   delta = -e.detail;
  }
  delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, delta)) // cap the delta to [-1,1] for cross browser consistency

  pos += -delta * speed
  pos = Math.max(0, Math.min(pos, target.scrollHeight - target.clientHeight + 15)) // + value from SMOOTH

  if (!moving) update()
 }

 function update() {
  moving = true
  var delta = (pos - target.scrollTop) / smooth
  target.scrollTop += delta
  if (Math.abs(delta) > 0)
   requestFrame(update)
  else
   moving = false
 }

 var requestFrame = function() { // requestAnimationFrame cross browser
  return (
   window.requestAnimationFrame ||
   window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
   window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
   window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
   window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
   function(func) {
    window.setTimeout(func, 1000 / 50);
   }
  );
 }()
}
```

```css
p {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<body onload="Scrollbar()">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</body>
```

**SOLVED! Code is UPDATED**

1. Add **+ 15** at the end `Math.max(0, Math.min(pos, target.scrollHeight - target.clientHeight + 15))` (15 is my smooth value, you set yours from `new SmoothScroll(document,65,15)`
2. Replace `Math.abs(delta) > 0.5` with `Math.abs(delta) > 0`
3. Speed = number + smooth (for speed 50 with smooth 15 write 65 in my example)

Answer (score 0):

lol your question is my solution because im tryin to look for a way to make scrollbar like this site https://www.carbonbeauty.com/, thanks man

Comment: I fixed bugs. I've updated the code. Look at the end of my question for the solution or copy the updated code :)